# ActionBar cannot be resolved to a type persist

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I get this error :

```
ActionBar cannot be resolved to a type
```

On the following line :

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
    ActionBar.TabListener {
```

Upgrading both ADT and the support library to the last version didn't work.

I also tried as suggested in many places to add :

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

Note that I am using actionbarsherlock.

Comment: Why do you extends SherlockFragmentActivity if you are using standard support.v7.library?

Comment: Yeah kinda useless. I guess it is more about despair and google search. I remove this line, the problem still remain though.

Comment: You should extend ActionBarActivity if you are using official library